# Android DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am using Android `DownloadManager` to download some file say of `XMB` if `DownloadManager` completes download it will send `broadcast` of action `android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` in normal scenario.

My question is what if the internet connection gets lost in between. Will it send any broadcast? Same case in between if server stops serving what `DownloadManager` does. Maybe its silly question, I have very small file so I am unable to test this scenario.

Could some one tell me what `DownloadManager` does in these kind of scenarios?

Answer (score 2):

The broadcast will be sent. You need to check the status of `DownloadManager` to determine if it was successful. For example:

```
private DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
            long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
            Query query = new Query();
            query.setFilterById(enqueue);
            Cursor c = dm.query(query);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                    // handle data
                } else if (DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                    // handle error
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

For a full example, see: [this link](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/). For ways to determine the reason of the failure, see [this link](http://android-er.blogspot.hu/2011/07/check-downloadmanager-status-and-reason.html).

Comment: so you mean to say every time ether success of failure it will send broadcast of action android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE ?

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy : [Android DownloadManager Example](https://androidclarified.com/android-downloadmanager-example/)

I register my receiver for **DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE** broadcast only. This is invoked only when the download is successfully completed

Follow this three steps

Create a BroadcastReceiver as shown in snippet below.Inside the receiver we just check if the received broadcast is for our download by matching the received download id with our enqueued download.

```
private BroadcastReceiver onDownloadComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           //Fetching the download id received with the broadcast
           long id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
           //Checking if the received broadcast is for our enqueued download by matching download id
           if (downloadID == id) {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Download Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }
   };
```

Once the BroadcastReceiver is created you can register for ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE in the onCreate method of your activity.

```
@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       registerReceiver(onDownloadComplete,new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

   }
```

It is also important that you unregister the BroadcastReceiver in onDestroy. This ensures you only listen for this broadcast as long as the activity is active

```
@Override
  public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      unregisterReceiver(onDownloadComplete);
  }
```

Complete example [here](https://androidclarified.com/android-downloadmanager-example/)